# Can TypeScript tell me which strings in my codebase are "unsafe"?

Tags: typescript

We have "safe" strings in our TypeScript codebase:

```
button.on('click', () => {}); // mistyping 'click' is an error
```

but also unsafe strings:

```
_.omit(obj, 'a'); // no error if I mistype 'a'
```

Is there a way to list such strings? I guess TypeScript has the knowledge about it but I'm not sure if it can be dug out of it.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking and apparently neither was the person who answered.  Could you provide a [mcve] so that others can see what you mean by "safe" and "unsafe", and in particular: "list"?  Like, you want the compiler or your IDE to generate a list of all the functions in your code that take a `string` parameter instead of a union of string literals?   Maybe this is something the [compiler api](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#traversing-the-ast-with-a-little-linter) could give you but I doubt you can get it by pushing a button somewhere.

Comment: You're exactly right, it's about generating a list of "weakly typed" strings, maybe via TypeScript's programmatic API, maybe via eslint-typescript, I don't know how to do it but I'd like to scan our codebase for such things.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a type containing only safe values:

```
export type SafeValue = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';

export function omit(param: SafeValue) {
   ...
}

omit('a'); // error
```

If you want to know if 'a' is a property of `obj` instead, you can do something like this:

```
export function omit<T>(object: T, property: keyof T) {
  payload[value]; // this statement is safe
}
```

For example, if you have the class Person:

```
export class Person {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}
```

The statement `keyof Person` will be equal to `'name' | 'age'`.

```
 const person = new Person();

 omit<Person>(person, 'age'); // won't emit any error

 omit<Person>(person, 'paws'); // will emit an error:
```

> Argument of type '"paws"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"name" | "age"'

Comment: I know such code can be written, the question is whether it's possible to "query" TypeScript for weakly typed strings.

Comment: What do you mean for "weakly typed strings"?